# Function textField catches mistake but still displays bad character

Tags: swift, textfield

In the function textField, the second part (starting with 'let ...') performs perfectly by finding whenever more than one decimal point has been attempted to be entered into a textField, and does not allow more than one decimal point to be displayed in a textField.

The problem is that in the first part. Here it tries to first find if an alphabetic character has been typed. It does recognize that happening, and exits returning 'false'.

Unlike the 'repeated decimal finding part of the code, the textField displays the bad character rather than skipping it.

Maybe I don't understand how this delegated method is intended to work.  I though the method somehow when it returns false it prevents that character from being added to the textField display.

```
func textField(_ textField:UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    for scalar in (textField.text?.unicodeScalars)! {
      if NSCharacterSet.letters.contains(scalar) {
        print("letter scalar found: \(scalar.value),  false")
        return false
      }
    }

    let existingTextHasDecimalSeperator = textField.text?.range(of: ".")  // search textField for '.', can be 'nil'
    let replacementTextHasDecimalSeperator = string.range(of: ".")        // next character is '.',    can be 'nil'
    if existingTextHasDecimalSeperator != nil, replacementTextHasDecimalSeperator != nil {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could store the results of the statements in a `Bool` and return it using `&&` between the two `Bool` values.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're searching the existing textField.text, not the new character (`replacementString`) for alpha characters.

Change `(textField.text?.unicodeScalars)!` to `string.unicodeScalars` and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(_ textField:UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    for scalar in string.unicodeScalars {
      if NSCharacterSet.letters.contains(scalar) {
        print("letter scalar found: \(scalar.value),  false")
        return false
      }
    }

    let existingTextHasDecimalSeperator = textField.text?.range(of: ".")  // search textField for '.', can be 'nil'
    let replacementTextHasDecimalSeperator = string.range(of: ".")        // next character is '.',    can be 'nil'
    if existingTextHasDecimalSeperator != nil, replacementTextHasDecimalSeperator != nil {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
```

The suggestion of replacing the search from textField to string works!  Here is a listing of the swift 3.0 version that works.